# Compare Sonar Qube result from different Git branches

Tags: git, tfs, sonarqube

We use Sonar Qube to collect metrics about our project. We use Git as version control system. Each project has a Master repository and several team contribute to this via pull requests of their branches. We make nightly build and releases of the master, this includes Sonar analysis.

We would like to configure Sonar Qube in such a manner that it compares the pull request builds data with the data of the master build. That way the quality gates can catch deviations *before* they become  part of the master and not after as is the case now.

Is this possible and can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Seems the question is more related to Sonarqube side, not related to TFS tag.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT Probably, that is why that tag is in there too. TFS is in there to indicate that we use/configre SonarQube with TFS build steps.

Comment: There is a open source Branch Plugin for SonarQube Community Edition https://github.com/s-pw/sonar-branch-community that support diff quality gates for branches.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the free sq version I don't think you can do this. A workaround could be using the deprecated sonar.branch parameter.

Create the feature branch from master, run the analysis with the desired branch name and sq will create a new project for this branch.
All subsequent issues on this branch will be treated as in a normal project, so if you add issues on the feature branch you will know at once.